# High Availability of Gearman Server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, high-availability, gearman

I am using Jenkins with Gearman Plugin to achieve master-master high availability in Jenkins. But now the single point of failure has become the Gearman-Server.

Gearman Plugin allows me to connect to only one Gearman-Server at a time, So how can I achieve High Availability for Gearman Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple Gearman servers (i.e. run one for each Jenkins master) and have them all persist their queues to the same database (which can also be distributed).

This protects you against the loss of jobs if a single Gearman server fails, but note that Gearman servers do not sync their queues with persistent storage until restarted. More on this here: [What's best practice for HA gearman job servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664701/whats-best-practice-for-ha-gearman-job-servers)